# Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied user 'a4996215'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
$sitename = "xxxxxx";

$link = mysql_connect("xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx");

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('xxxxxx', $link);

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

function fetchinfo($rowname,$tablename,$finder,$findervalue) {

    if($finder == "1") $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename");

    else $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename WHERE `$finder`='$findervalue'");

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    return $row[$rowname];
}
?>
```

> Im getting error from the line `else $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename WHERE`$finder`='$findervalue'");` ive searched little around but i didnt seem to work (also its my first time posting so sorry if it looks bad

Comment: Before you break your head with that issue, you should migrate to **PDO** instead of using **deprecated** mysql_* functions. They will be removed as of PHP 7.

Comment: That means one of three things: (1) You didn't specify a password, but should have. (2) That account doesn't have SELECT privileges. (3) Something else is wrong - but not with the shown code, but your local setup, which we can't help with.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Thank you for answer. Its weird when i log in with a proxy to my site everything works fine